# Random Binary Read/Write in Python vs .NET

Tags: python, .net, vb.net, file-io, binaryfiles

I really like how .NET implements reading/writing of binary data to a file. Clean and elegant.

Can I do this in Python?

```
Sub Main()
    Using writer As New System.IO.BinaryWriter( _
    System.IO.File.Open("Test.bin", IO.FileMode.Create))
        writer.Write(True)
        writer.Write(123)
        writer.Write(123.456)
        writer.Write(987.654D)
        writer.Write("Test string.")
    End Using
    Using reader As New System.IO.BinaryReader( _
    System.IO.File.Open("Test.bin", IO.FileMode.Open))
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadBoolean())
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadInt32())
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadDouble())
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadDecimal())
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString())
    End Using
    Console.Write("Press <RETURN> to exit.")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. Use ´with´ with open, see the example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open `with open("file.txt") as file:`

Comment: Yes, I understand context managers, but how can I write a `bool`, `int`, `float`, `str`, `decimal.Decimal`, etc. I have seen solutions that write whole structures, like lists or classes, for example using the `pickle` module, but not so much individual values. That is why I used 'Random' in the question title.

Comment: Ahh, I see. But I don't think something like that exists in python. Use pickle...